# How to pull data from rss feed into iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am creating an iPhone app in which data needs to be pulled from a wordpress that I created. The data that needs to be displayed is the statistics of our local groups. I have the background that I need. Can I put a table view over the background so that when it runs it will look like a lineup card. I am very new to this so laymen's terms would be appreciated.
Respectfully, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

Answer (score 2):

You can read a tutorial from http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Set the UITableView and UITableViewCells' backgroundColor properties to `[UIColor clearColor]` so that you can see your background underneath it.

Comment: Awesome thats what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: @GabrielWebb I'm glad it helped. On Stack Overflow one should vote up answers that helped (like saturngod's) and mark *the* answer so that the question isn't left open.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'm still a bit confused as to how i actually set up the app the way i want it. I want it to look like a lineup card for a team.

Comment: You simply need to align the height of the table cells and their labels to fit within the framework of your lineup card image. If you don't know how to do that, Googling the specifics of each step necessary will help you find the answers.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have the labels update with and rss feed ? is it simple or is it gonna be difficult this is my first real application?

Comment: It's possible to use content from the RSS feed populate the labels if that's what you mean

Comment: yes that is what i'm trying to get but it is hard for me to understand how that is done. Every tutorial I've seen just shows how to make an RSS Feed Reader App not pull the data from it and display certain words from it into assigned labels. Any help guidance or direction would help a lot. I will up vote as soon as my rep allows it.